# Is it possible to test dm's multipath driver without a physical multipath device?

Tags: linux, device-mapper, multipath

I need to test a scenario that one of our customers has run across using a multipath device. I was hoping to be able to set up a device mapper using the multipath driver pointing to a loop or physical disk or something, because I don't actually have a multipath device handy.

I tried this:

```
dmsetup create mpathtest --table '0 819200 multipath  0  0  1  1 round-robin 0 1 1 7:7 1'
```

`7:7` is `/dev/loop7` for those of you who haven't memorized the loop driver major number.

That gets me this:

```
kernel: device-mapper: table: table load rejected: including non-request-stackable devices
```

There's little discussion on this in the google. I know `dm` is a stacking block driver and loop is too, but apparently not a request-stackable driver. Are there any request-stackable drivers I can use to test this locally?

CentOS 6.8 is the target, but anything will do.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a limitation of the 2.6.32 kernel that ships with centos 6.8.

I tried it on ubuntu 16.04 (4.4.0) and the dm create worked.

I think not all the pieces existed in 2.6.32 to make it work. Loop changed a lot for example.

Wasn't able to reproduce the customer's problem, but at least I was able to create a dm with the multipath driver.